# ActiveRecord "SHOW TABLES" queries

Tags: activerecord, resque

I'm using Rails 2.3 for my project, with Resque for processing background tasks.

ActiveRecord usually does a "SHOW TABLES" and "SHOW FIELDS FROM" query the first time you use any model, then caches it. My issue is that Resque forks a new process for every job, so this is never cached, and ActiveRecords run those queries again on every job.

What is the recommended way to force ActiveRecord to cache these queries?
Adding "Model.inspect" for most of my models in an initializer helps, but a few "SHOW TABLES" queries still remain.

Answer (score 1):

In your rake task that you have to do environment initialization for resque, add the following snippet:

```
  # Make sure we've pre-loaded all of the schema information
  Resque.before_first_fork do
    ActiveRecord::Base.send(:subclasses).each { |klass| klass.columns }
  end
```

for example, in a `lib/tasks/resque.rake`:

```
task :resque_environment => :environment do
  # Make sure we've pre-loaded all of the schema information
  Resque.before_first_fork do
    ActiveRecord::Base.send(:subclasses).each { |klass| klass.columns }
  end
end
```